# How do I read all the SMS messages from a user mobile which have the keyword "amount" in them using my Android app and store it in Database?

Tags: android, sms

I've an app by which I need to read the user's SMS which contains the keyword "Amount" in it and store the number of that user in the database. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: I've given the permission to read the sms but unable to fetch them. Not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have already developed reading all the sms from user mobile
Use the below code

```
public void getAllSms()
{
    try
    {
        Calendar calendar;
        long milliSeconds;
        String finalDateString;
        int month;
        SmsMessage smsMessage;
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list2 = new ArrayList();
        DateFormat formatter, formatter3;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), "android.permission.READ_SMS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (int idx = 0; idx < cursor.getCount() && idx < 100; idx++) {

                        milliSeconds = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
                        formatter3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd hh:mm:ss");
                        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        month = calendar.getTime().getMonth() + 1;
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
                        finalDateString = formatter.format(calendar.getTime()) + "-" + String.format("%02d",month) + "-" + formatter3.format(calendar.getTime());

                        if (idx < 50) {
                            smsMessage = new SmsMessage();
                            smsMessage.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")));
                            smsMessage.setMessage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Telephony.Sms.BODY)));
                            smsMessage.setCreatedTime(finalDateString);

                            list.add(smsMessage);
                        } 
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }

                } else {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("error","cathc");
    }
}
```

Note: you need to check the cursor is null or not

Comment: SmsMessage is Json response class you can delete it but use the parameters for getting the sms content's